# Can we change the unicode version being used by java?

Tags: java, unicode, version

Java 7 supports Unicode 6.0 . Unicode 4.0 support is restricted to versions 5.0 and 6.0 of the Java platform.

Unicode 6.2.0 is a minor version of the Unicode Standard and supersedes all previous versions.
Version 6.2 of the Unicode Standard is a special release dedicated to the early publication of the newly encoded Turkish lira sign.

Is it possible to use this latest 6.2 version in the web application which uses java 7?

Comment: looks like you'll need to wait around for jdk8 - http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/133

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're after, but if you don't need character properties or a name of the lira sign, then there's no reason why you cannot use it. As far as the *code points* are concerned, Java is just doing what you say. As long as you have a font that can render it you can use any character you like. Java won't check its internal Unicode character database whether that code point is indeed used and refuse to display it if not.

Where this breaks down is where character properties are needed or algorithms that have been updated. But the lira sign is a pretty normal character for that purposes, it would probably be different if you were trying to use U+XNEW COMBINING AWESOMENESS BELOW, but even that likely requires more font than application support.

Answer (score 3):

you could input and output unicode-6.2-encoded text if you move your project to use [icu](http://site.icu-project.org/) instead of using characters and strings from jdk libraries. the latest version of icu [supports unicode 6.2](http://site.icu-project.org/download/50).
to render it to screen you'll need a compatible font, but if youre writing a web-app (that outputs text/html) thats not your concern.
if you want to have java built-in classes support unicode 6.2 you'll need to wait for jdk8 - http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/133